# prove that $\tan2x=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{1-2\sin^2x}$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $$\tan2x=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{1-2\sin^2x}$$

I thought that I could simply write $\sin2x$ divided by $\cos 2x$ gives $\tan 2x$ but the question carries 3 marks. Is there a descriptive proof to solve this?

Comment: That’s the most efficient method already.

Comment: So there's no descriptive proof?

Comment: What do you mean by descriptive proof?

Comment: I mean to ask whether can I prove $tan2x$ by simplifying these equations. As I mentioned earlier this question carries 3 marks

Comment: Does "3 marks" mean $30$% of the total score?

Comment: If "3 marks" typically indicates a difficult exercise, then congratulate yourself on finding it too easy. There really isn't any more to this than you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2\sin x \cos x=\sin 2x$, while $1-2\sin^2x=\sin^2 x+\cos^2x-2\sin^2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos2x$

Thus $$\tan 2x=\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x}$$

Comment: You don't have to prove $1-2\sin^2x=\cos 2x$: it is one of the basic *duplication formulæ*.

Comment: Do you think the exercise is about proving that $\tan (f(x))=\sin(f(x))/\cos(f(x))$?